# Shape resizing animation on orientation change

Tags: swiftui

I have an issue with the shadow shape not being animated at the same time as the discs.

[image]

[image]

Here's the corresponding code. You can test this on an iPad by changing the orientation.
This is a direct consequence of the ContentView. Removing the GeometryReader and using a fixed frame fixes it.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack {
                PlanetView()
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.25, height: geometry.size.width * 0.25)
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        }
    }
}

struct PlanetView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack {
                Circle()
                    .fill(.blue)

                Circle()
                    .foregroundColor(.green)
                    .overlay(PlanetShadowView())
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.8, height: geometry.size.width * 0.8)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct PlanetShadowView: View {
    var offsetRatio: CGFloat = 15/100.0
    
    func control1(_ size: CGSize) -> CGPoint {
        let xOffset = offsetRatio * size.width
        let yOffset = offsetRatio * size.height
        return .init(x: xOffset, y: size.height - yOffset)
    }

    func control2(_ size: CGSize) -> CGPoint {
        let xOffset = offsetRatio * size.width
        let yOffset = offsetRatio * size.height
        return .init(x: size.width - xOffset, y: size.height - yOffset)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            Path { path in
                path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: geometry.size.height / 2))
                path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: geometry.size.width, y: geometry.size.height / 2),
                              control1: control1(geometry.size),
                              control2: control2(geometry.size))
                path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: geometry.size.width / 2, y: geometry.size.height / 2),
                            radius: geometry.size.width / 2,
                            startAngle: Angle(degrees: 0),
                            endAngle: Angle(degrees: 180),
                            clockwise: false)
                path.closeSubpath()
            }
            .fill(Color.black.opacity(0.25))
            .rotationEffect(.degrees(-30))
        }
    }
}

struct PlanetView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PlanetView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `.drawingGroup()`?

Comment: @ChrisR I had not, and this is the solution. Post this as an answer and I will accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

A solution for this is to make planet shadow as a shape, so it would render in the same `GeometryReader` transformation context as everything else.

[image: demo]

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

```
                Circle()
                    .foregroundColor(.green)
                    .overlay(
                        PlanetShadow()           // << here !!
                            .fill(Color.black.opacity(0.25))
                            .rotationEffect(.degrees(-30)))
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.8, height: geometry.size.width * 0.8)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct PlanetShadow: Shape {             // << here !!
    var offsetRatio: CGFloat = 15/100.0

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
       // calc here ...
```

[Test module on GitHub](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/TestShapeAnimationAlignment.swift)

Comment: This doesn't work on iPad though. I was surprised because I had already tried to do exactly that :/

Answer (score 1):

Add `.drawingGroup()`. This should render the composition as a whole before displaying it.

Comment: Sorry, I have to un-accept this because it has serious side effects I did not spot at the time. By rendering the view into a bitmap, it messes with other subviews.

Comment: no worries, it's always try and error :)